# GCC Makefile Error: -std=c99 and -lm

Tags: makefile, linker, flags

I've been trying for quite long to adapt my makefile to work with -std=c99 and -lm. The code above work fine without -std=c99, but doesn't compile when I have this flag. I tried [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976302/gcc-makefile-doesnt-accept-std-c99-lm), as it's the same problem I'm facing, but I can't make it work.

```
CC = gcc -std=c99
PARAMETERS = -g -Wall
LIB = -lm

jacobi: jacobi.o
    $(CC) $(PARAMETERS) jacobi.o -o jacobi $(LIB)

jacobi.o: jacobi.c
    $(CC) $(PARAMETERS) -c jacobi.c -o jacobi.o $(LIB)

clean:
    rm -f *.o jacobi *~
```

Could someone kindly help me? Thanks!

Comment: What is the actual failure that you are having?

Comment: I can't use, for example, the 'M_PI' constant. It seems I'm not linking the math library correctly in my makefile.

Comment: What **exact** error are you getting? From what command?

Comment: Ok, nevermind. The problem wasn't with my makefile... I had to put #define _GNU_SOURCE at the top of my 'jacobi.c' file in order to make -std=c99 and -lm flags work together.